# WebStorm shows deprecation error in postMessage function of a web worker

Tags: web, webstorm, deprecated, worker, postmessage

When writing something like this in WebStorm:

```
let webWorker = new Worker('...')
...
webWorker.postMessage(...)
```

The `postMessage` is striked out with the following message:

> "Deprecated symbol used, consult docs for better alternative"
>   "Checks for using deprecated JavaScript functions and variables ..."

Is `postMessage` function of the webWorker is deprecated?

Comment: Was the typo `Wroker` in your actual code or just in the post?

Comment: @faintsignal just in the post :)
Fixing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method is annotated with `@deprecated` tag in `lib.dom.d.ts` provided by Microsoft (that, in turn, was auto-generated from the webidl definition of edge); Microsoft has recently fixed the issue in https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24669, method is no more marked deprecated in https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts.

Webstorm will bundle Typescript 3.x that includes the fix in upcoming 2018.2.1 update (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-34144)